# Isomorphism of modules arising from algebraic topology

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-topology

While studying for a course in algebraic topology, the following question popped out:

> Let $S,R$ be two commutative rings with unit, $A,B$ two $S$-modules, and assume that $R$ is also an $S$-module. Is it true that:
>   $$\hom_S(A\otimes_SB,R)\cong\hom_S(A,R)\otimes_R\hom_S(B,R)$$
>   holds in general? And if not, under what kind of assumptions it could hold?

A little background could be of help. In our case, we had a map $f:S_p(X)\otimes_\mathbb{Z}S_q(Y)\to R$ (where $S_\bullet(X)$ is the singular chain complex on $X$), and a while later, the same map had to become an element of $S^p(X;R)\otimes_RS^q(Y;R)$ for a construction to work out. Thus in the question it would be enough to assume that $S=\mathbb{Z}$ and that $A,B$ are free abelian groups.

I tried to prove this for a while, and I think I got close to something looking like a proof for the simplified case exposed above (using generators of $A$ and $B$ and explicit homomorphisms between modules), however I'm not sure about all of the steps. I would really like an elegant proof relying on universal properties (or category theory), or a simple counterexample, if the statement is not true.

Answer (score 4):

There is a canonical homomorphism from $\hom_S(A,R) \otimes_R \hom_S(B,R)$ to $\hom_S(A \otimes_S B,R)$. The question is if this is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

It is true when $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated and projective (the standard proof works - show that $S$ works and that the class of "good" modules is closed under direct sums as well as direct summands).

Otherwise, it doesn't hold (even when $R=S$ is a field).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have an easy example of when it doesn't work? Also, in the special case of interest it would work, if instead of the singular complex we took the cellular complex, right?

Comment: The counterexample is contained in my answer. Read carefully.

Comment: Ok, got it. What about my second question?

Answer (score 2):

If we think of a map $F \in Hom(V \otimes V,k)$ as a matrix with $A_{ij} = F(e_i \otimes e_j)$, where $\{e_j\}$ is a basis of $V$, then in the finite dimensional case, we can recover any map $\hom(V \otimes V, k)$ as a finite sum of matricies of the form $vw^T$, which is what an element of $\hom(V, k) \otimes \hom(V,k)$ essentially is under the canonical map. The easiest way to do this is just take one appropriately scaled $\delta_i^T\delta_j$ for each entry of the matrix and add them up.

However, in the infinite dimensional case, the *finite sums* from $\hom(V,k) \otimes \hom(V,k)$ aren't enough to catch all the functions in $\hom(V\otimes V,k)$. An easy way to see this is to observe that the rank of an operator of the form $vw^T$ is finite dimensional, and so any finite sum of these will also have an finite dimensional rank.